# Kendo Grid rows not showing

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a pretty basic grid using the razor wrapper and my anticipated 3 rows are not showing up.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ManageUserViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.UserName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.LastName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Email);
        columns.Bound(c => c.LastNameFirstLetter).Hidden(true);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("list", "User"))
    )
)
```

Here is the json being returned from /User/list which I ran through jsonLint to make sure it was valid.

```
[{"UserName":"dfeinberg","FirstName":null,"LastName":null,"Email":"daniel.feinberg@rcsg.com","Password":null,"Roles":[],"LastNameFirstLetter":""},{"UserName":"jmarley","FirstName":"Jacob","LastName":"Marley","Email":"ebuntom@gmail.com","Password":null,"Roles":[{"Id":"9a0af7ad-e38f-4300-a49e-1051dc18c8e4","Name":"Administrator","Checked":false}],"LastNameFirstLetter":"M"},{"UserName":"tcoakley","FirstName":"Tom","LastName":"Coakley","Email":"tom.coakley@redcedarsolutionsgroup.com","Password":null,"Roles":[],"LastNameFirstLetter":"C"}]
```

Comment: I get the column headers, but the <tbody> tags remain empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my day for dumb questions.  My issue was not understanding the correct way to return the datasource from the controller.  Here is my corrected controller method.

```
public ActionResult List([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<AspNetUser> users = SdContext.AspNetUser.ToList();
    var models = UserAssembler.GetManageUserViewModels(users);

    return Json(models.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```